# Why is the FLA current so much higher than the actual running current?

Tags: current, amperage

In most cases I should say, when user a motor the actual running current seems to be a ton less than the FLA, resulting in me feeling like I over sized my conductors by a long shot.

Comment: I bet you're disappointed. You have my sympathy.

Comment: I am :( haha, in all actuality I don't really care in the sense it will effect my work, just curious as to why it happens every time.

Comment: @user1888260 I will try to effect change [here](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/affect.html)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I apologize for using the wrong word, I hope you can forgive as easy as you can supply people like me with some good knowledge.

Comment: @user1888260 No problem, I hope you can forgive the off-topic grammar comment.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146709/why-is-the-fla-current-so-much-higher-than-the-actual-running-current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLA stands for full-load amperes. If your current is less than the full-load amperes when the motor is running with full voltage, that should tell you something about your load. Perhaps it is not "full-load" but is rather somewhat less.

The more load you put on the motor, up to and including (and beyond) full rated load, the current will increase. You might think the ultimate would be with the rotor stalled (LRA = locked rotor amperes), but it can actually be worse again if the motor is 'plugged'.

Naturally such abuse can possibly damage the motor, the motors will typically quickly overheat if they are stalled (though some are designed to withstand stalling).